# OpenGL directx model

Tags: opengl, directx, model

Как загрузить и инициализировать модель в формате x в opengl?

Comment: @DaffyDoomer, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать [Open Asset Import Library](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Asset_Import_Library).

Она кроссплатформенная, поддерживает множество форматов, в том числе .x, ее легко использовать. Вот оттуда код примера использования:

```
// Create an instance of the Importer class
  Assimp::Importer importer;
  // And have it read the given file with some example postprocessing
  // Usually - if speed is not the most important aspect for you - you'll 
  // propably to request more postprocessing than we do in this example.
  const aiScene* scene = importer.ReadFile( pFile, 
        aiProcess_CalcTangentSpace       | 
        aiProcess_Triangulate            |
        aiProcess_JoinIdenticalVertices  |
        aiProcess_SortByPType);

  // If the import failed, report it
  if( !scene)
  {
    DoTheErrorLogging( importer.GetErrorString());
    return false;
  }
  // Now we can access the file's contents. 
  DoTheSceneProcessing( scene);
```

В функции DoTheSceneProcessing подразумевается ваша реализация использования полученных данных (создание индексных и вершинных буферов, буферов с координатами текстур и нормалями, заполнение их данными из объекта scene).

Поскольку в один файл может быть упакована целая сцена, с источниками света, моделями и материалами, для навигации по импортированной иерархии служит соответствующая система узлов.

```
if (scene->HasMeshes())
{
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<scene->mNumMeshed; i++)
        LoadMesh(scene->mMeshes[i]);
}
```

Добравшись по дереву узлов до самой модели, можно получить непосредственно данные о вершинах.

```
void LoadMesh(aiMesh *mesh)
{
    GLuint VBO;
    glGenBuffer(1,&VBO);  // создаем Vertex Buffer Object
    // тут должна быть обработка ошибок, если VBO не был успешно создан
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,VBO);  // Говорим созданному буферу, что он будет хранить вершины
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,mesh->mNumVeretices,mesh->mVertices,GL_STATIC_DRAW); // Копируем данные из модели в буфер
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Разобраться с форматом файла, распарсить да и загрузить. В итоге модель будет представлять собой пачку массивов с координатами вершин, порядком их обхода для построения треугольников, нормалями, текстурными координатами и прочей фигней. Естественно, можно загнать это все в класс (вы на с++ пишете?) и запилить волшебный метод `draw()`, который пропихнет эти массивы в пайплайн видеокарты.

Писал в свое время для формата 3ds - задача в общем не сложная.

---

Или найти формат попроще (если вдруг с .х какие трудности возникнут), написать загрузчик под него и сконвертировать ваши модели в этот формат. Помню была отличная софтина, которая умела массу форматов моделей ворочать - DeepExploration.